# Binary operator '+=' cannot be applied to operands of type '[Dictionary<String, String>]' and 'Dictionary<String, String>'

Tags: ios, swift

I tried debugging my ios app in xcode using swift which I'm making a task app but I'm getting the error "'+=' cannot be applied to operands of type '[Dictionary]' and 'Dictionary'. The following error is happening in one of my functions which the code is below. How do I get around this error by applying "+=" using the Dictionary type?

Code:

```
func taskCreated(task: Dictionary<String, String>) {
    println("in task created delegate of ViewController")
    println(task)

    dataSource[0] += task

    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Edit: My Declaration of dataSource

```
var dataSource: [[Dictionary<String, String>]] = [[], []]
```

Comment: Can you post the code that declares dataSource.

Comment: Done. I posted an edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to append a dictionary to an array of array of dictionaries.  Use `append()` on the selected array:

```
dataSource[0].append(task)
```